# How to check for no argument sent to a function in Python

Tags: python, function, conditional-statements

So, within a function I would like to test for the presence of an argument the function is expecting.  If there is an argument, do this, if no argument is sent form the calling programme and none is received into the function do that.

```
def do_something(calculate):
    if calculate == something expected:
        do this
    elif calculate not sent to function:
        do that
```

So what would be the logical test/expression I'd need to check for to test if no argument was received into the function please?

Comment: If your function signature mentions argument and your function call doesnt provide the exact number of arguments, python  throws an error.

Comment: Your function can't be called without arguments, passing in a value for `calculate` is *mandatory*.

Comment: According to a coding exercise on exercise.io - it asks for a certain course of action if no argument is given into the function. So... err...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could set the `argument` as `None`, and check if it is passed or not,

```
def do_something(calculate=None):
    if calculate is None:
        # do that
        return 'Whatever'
    if calculate == "something expected":
        # do this
    return 'Whateverelse'
```

Comment: Have tried but it still doesn't do what I wish.  Specifically I am running an exercise from exercism.io where I have to write some code for Two-fer or 2-fer which is short for two for one. One for you and one for me.

"One for X, one for me."
When X is a name or "you".

If the given name is "Alice", the result should be "One for Alice, one for me." If no name is given, the result should be "One for you, one for me."  The code I have written is failing on the 'If no name is given" part.

Comment: Running this code in Pytest gives an error def two_fer(name=None):
    if name == 'Alice' or name == 'Bob':
        return ('One for ' + str(name) + ", one for me.")
    elif name == False:
        return ('One for you, one for me.')

Comment: __________________________________________________ TwoFerTest.test_no_name_given __________________________________________________

self = <two_fer_test.TwoFerTest testMethod=test_no_name_given>

    def test_no_name_given(self):
>       self.assertEqual(two_fer(), 'One for you, one for me.')
E       AssertionError: None != 'One for you, one for me.'

two_fer_test.py:10: AssertionError
=============================================== 1 failed, 2 passed in 0.07 seconds ================================================

Comment: Sorry about the lack of formatting, I am not sure how to format code in the comment replies.

Comment: When I start the def with def two_fer(name): and run Pytest, I get the following error TypeError: two_fer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Comment: `def two_fer(name=None)`. Please note the `name='None'`

Comment: Many thanks @han solo - that worked a treat.  I see it was done with two if statements rather than one if statement and an else or elif.  Thank you.