How to programmatically determine if the default parameter value was used?
Given a function:
def foo(num = 42, bar = 100):
    print("num:", num)

How might I add code to foo to learn if foo was invoked with no argument for the num and/or bar parameters?

You can look into this response:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55025149/how-to-check-for-no-argument-sent-to-a-function-in-python

Thank you for your considerate suggestion, but that's not what I'm asking for.

You might use decorator for unveiling what arguments were passed following way
def show_arguments(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Positional arguments', args)
        print('Keyword arguments', kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@show_arguments
def foo(num = 42, bar = 100):
    print("num:", num)


foo()
foo(1)
foo(num=1)
foo(1,bar=1)
foo(num=1,bar=1)

gives output
Positional arguments ()
Keyword arguments {}
num: 42
Positional arguments (1,)
Keyword arguments {}
num: 1
Positional arguments ()
Keyword arguments {'num': 1}
num: 1
Positional arguments (1,)
Keyword arguments {'bar': 1}
num: 1
Positional arguments ()
Keyword arguments {'num': 1, 'bar': 1}
num: 1

Observe that function in python are 1st class citizens.

Thank you for your kind response. That's a great solution.

foo still doesn't know if the arguments were passed.  Only the wrapper knows.

One way is to use inspect.signature. The only limitation is that the function has to be written in pure Python.
import inspect


def default_arg_checker(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # signature of the target function
        sig = inspect.signature(func)

        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            p_default_value = sig.parameters[k].default
            if p_default_value != v:
                print(f'the default value of "{k}" changed: {p_default_value} -> {v}')

        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@default_arg_checker
def foo(num=42, bar=100):
    pass


foo(num=420)

Output
the default value of "num" changed: 42 -> 420


Will that work if the argument is equal to the default value in the parameter?

works it works... but maybe we are using different standards:) This code with foo(bar=100) will not show anything. Is this what you expecting?

to detect foo(bar=100) add the following else condition: else:                 print(f'attempt to change the default value {v} of "{k}" (both values are equal!)') which will output attempt to change the default value 100 of "bar" (both values are equal!)
